# Explode JavaScript regular expression for password strength

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression used to check my password validity (I found it in the internet). It checks the minlenght of 6 characters, at least one upper, at least one lower, at least one number, and a symbol. I want to explode this regex and put it in an array so that I can check the passwords strength.

```js
var regexp = /^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!]).{6,})$/
```

Then I'll have something like this:

```js
if(regexparray[0].test(passwordval)){
    strenght++;
} else if(regexparray[1].test(passwordval)){
    strenght++;
} 
//etc....
```

EDIT: What is the proper way to divide this regex into its parts?

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Give it a try and come back with a specific question.

Comment: my question is how the right way is to explode that regexp! I just took it from the internet and don't know how it works. I never used reg.exp. before

Comment: `regexparray[0] = /(?=.*\d)/; regexparray[1] = /(?=.*[a-z])/;` and so on... every parenthesis is a group...

Comment: Ok. what about the ^ at the start and $ at the end? have i to add them on every element of the array?

Comment: This doesn't check password strength.  It checks a weak proxy for password strength.  What's worse, because it prevents strong, easily remembered pass phrases (see https://xkcd.com/936/ ), _and_ encourages users to write down their passwords, it most likely reduces security.  Please, if you have any say in the matter, do not implement this rule.

Comment: ok do you think it is better if I only check the minimum length of the password, and let the user input a long password?

Comment: Pass *phrases* are typically considered better than pass *words*, but if all you're doing is checking length, there is nothing to prevent the user from entering 12345678901234567890 for a 20 character pass phrase. Instead, as @WayneConrad's comment suggests, the best thing to do would probably be to [calcualte the entropy of the password](https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/), but that gets complicated and according to the article, none of the 9 major websites listed are using entropy to determine password strength.

Comment: @Mike, good points.  One compromise is to use a password strength checker.  I've got good service out of password checkers such as libpwquality (although I cannot vouch for that particular one).  Many web frameworks have plugins to tie the authentication system into a password strength checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending Jorge Campos's comment, you could do something like this:

```
var passwordval = 'fdSfdDSF';

var tests = [
    '(?=.*\d)',
    '(?=.*[a-z])',
    '(?=.*[A-Z])',
    '(?=.*[@#$%!])',
    '.{6,}'
],
    strength = 0;

for (var i=0, l=tests.length; i<l; i++) {

    var re = new RegExp(tests[i]);

    if (re.test(passwordval)) {

        strength += 1;

    }

}

console.log(strength);
// 4
```

If you're grabbing user input from a form field you're probably already sanitizing the input a bit by doing something like `var passwordval = $.trim($('#password').val());`. Plus, you don't really need to restrict the tests with start and end of string metacharacters (`^` and `$`).

Comment: Thank you very much! bu what about the ^ at the start and $ at the end? aren't they important?

Comment: @Manuel, `^` means the beginning of the string and `$` means the end of the string. Leaving them out should be fine.